City planners choose to have only male trees, is that the reason for pollen allergies?
This video claims that the city planners intentionally avoided female trees which are supposed to absorb all the pollens to produce fruits and since there is an imbalance, there is more pollens in the air and that causes allergies. Is this really true??
https://www.tiktok.com/t/ZTLm8cbAh
https://youtube.com/shorts/6Mh-0iLGvc8

oh yeah, I meant male, corrected the question title

No, that's foolishness based on a lack of education.
Male trees produce far more pollen than female trees "absorb" by a very large amount. So pollen will be out in the air regardless of female trees, which only use a tiny fraction of it.
They plant male trees only to prevent fruiting, which they regard as (mostly) a city cleanup problem, and (somewhat cynically) as allowing the poor (or anyone else who chooses to gather it) to have free food "problem."
They don't plant only female trees, as pollen from a considerable distance, or a single male tree somewhere in the city would pollinate a great many of those and result in fruit.
The use of only male trees from species that have male and female trees does result in more pollen than a mixture of species and sexes would (i.e. if half the trees were female then there would be half as much pollen from that species, due to fewer male trees) but the idea that the amount the female trees remove from the air is significant is false.

Hi Ecnerwal, good answer but a reference would make it even better

Of course with ginkgos, the vomitballs produced by the females trees are a good reason to plant only the males. I sometimes wonder what animal in the distant past was attracted to the smell of those fruits.

I agree with Ecnerwal's answer above. A mix of female and male trees wouldn't mean no free pollen in the air at all, but it would reduce the amount of pollen if they were mixed. This article is 3 years old, but worth reading, since it is about this problem, though not specifically in reference to maple trees https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2020/may/16/how-urban-planners-preference-for-male-trees-has-made-your-hay-fever-worse
